# SQL Like but not within words regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I need help with regex for this

I am looking for the word "john" in my table. I start with a simple query

```
select * from tblA where Line like '%john%'
```

this OK. but I have results like "VarJohnA", or "WowJohnCool". The one I am specifically looking for is more like, for example

```
1. 'John ' (begins with J ends with white space)
2. ' John ' (begins with white space ends with white space)
3. 'John,' (begins with J ends with comma)
4. ',john,' (begins with comma ends with comma)
5. ' John,' (begins with white space ends with comma)
```

Now you may suggest to write a SQL like follows.

```
select * from tblA where Line like '% john %' 
or Line like 'john %' 
or Line like '%john,%' 
or Line like '%,john,%' 
or Line like '% john,%'
```

But this is not what I am looking for because the 5 bullets above is the one I can think of, there maybe myriad of

```
'"John"'
```

or

```
'"John'
```

or

```
'<John' 
'=John' 
'=John+'
```

and who knows what else.

I was thinking the more accurate result of what I am looking for is basically. I want to find "John" but "john" is not within a-z. 
so the regex would be something like

```
select * from tblA where line not like '[a-z]John[a-z]'
```

or

```
select * from tblA where line not like '%[^a-z]John[^a-z]%'
```

But none works.

but in short, I am looking for the word "John" but it john must not in between a-z characters.

please advise

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
where ' ' + replace(Line, ',', ' ') + ' ' like '% john %'
```

Or, for non-letters in general:

```
where ' ' + Line + ' ' like '%[^a-zA-Z]john[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

Comment: the second one works. but I am confused now, I would think it should be "NOT LIKE" instead of "LIKE" ?

Comment: @BobNoobGuy . . . I don't understand your confusion.  The goal is to find `'john'` in the column.